# AWS database for a simple service

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql

Which is the best AWS db for a simple microservice that has one table of data with potentially lots of fields per row.

The service will simply store data sent from an admin panel and then get queried by graphql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your simple description I would go with Amazon's DynamoDB. According to their docs:

"Amazon DynamoDB is a key-value and document database that delivers single-digit millisecond performance at any scale. It's a fully managed, multiregion, multimaster, durable database with built-in security, backup and restore, and in-memory caching for internet-scale applications. DynamoDB can handle more than 10 trillion requests per day and can support peaks of more than 20 million requests per second."

Seems to fulfill your needs.

Comment: I've taken the approach of prove to me that DynamoDB isn't the answer before I'll use something else.

Comment: If in our 'admin' panel we need to add a new field, is it easy to do that with dynamo? I.e add a new attribute that automatically adds it to all other rows in the db?